# Unable to update to Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-electric-eel

I was attempting the update to Patch 2 but it fails with the following message.

[image]

I was hoping to avoid uninstalling the old version. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download latest version from site https://developer.android.com/studio and check uninstall. It'll keep your data and settings.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by overwrite install?

Comment: Install on top of your current installation, without uninstall it.

Comment: This worked, I downloaded the latest version and it makes you close Android Studio if it's open. There is then a checkbox that says uninstall old version but none of your projects or configurations will be lost. It worked with all my plugins and configurations intact.

Comment: No it does not seem to like that. At least on Windows 10, there is "Please select an empty folder to install Android Studio" shown when I attempt to overwrite-install it.

Comment: @Cee I'm using Windows 10 as well and don't recall seeing that message.

Comment: OP since edited their answer, I got it now, worked, thanks

Comment: I'm on Windows 11 and have a 2020 AS installed, but with android-studio-2022.3.1.19-windows.exe, I don't see the uninstall checkbox and it's refusing to install to the same dir. Annoying. Will need to blow up the existing installation and install then.